# Kotlin ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add my dynamic list of data into dialog multiple select options and I'm receiving following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

`Code`

```
class PublishActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var tags: List<Tags>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_publish)

        // get api data
        getDynamicOptions()


        // get data into dialog
        pTags.setOnClickListener{
            val tagOptions = arrayOfNulls<String>(tags.size)
            Log.d("totalTags", tags.size.toString()) // returns: 387
            for (i in tags.indices) {
                tagOptions[i] = tags[i].title
            }

            var checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(false)
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.project_type))
                .setMultiChoiceItems(tagOptions, checkedItems) { dialog, which, checked ->
                    // Respond to item chosen
                    Log.d("eeee5", checkedItems.toString())
                }
                .show()
        }
    }


    // getting data from server
    private fun getDynamicOptions() {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/fetchData"

        val stringReq : StringRequest =
            object : StringRequest(
                Method.GET, url,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    val dataa = Gson().fromJson(response, PublisData::class.java)

                    // return received data into `lateinit var tags: List<Tags>`
                    tags = dataa.tags
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Log.d("eee2", error.toString())
                    Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            ){
                override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                    return headers
                }
            }
        queue.add(stringReq)
    }
}
```

**Note:** `lateinit var tags: List<Tags>` is list of tags I'm receiving from server and I intend to show them as options in my dialog

**Ps:** I also need my options to be included tag id's (is that possible to get both `title` and `id` into dialog options?

## Update

I've changed my code the following

```
var tagOptions = emptyArray<String>()
for (i in tags) {
  tagOptions = listOf(i.title).toTypedArray()
}
```

it does return my tags in dialog but it only shows `1 tag` out of `387 tags`!

Comment: not sure if this is the problem, but your code seems a bit redundant, there's no need to declare a complete array with nulls just to change it later, you can use `val foo = emptyArray<String>()` and then just add _in_ to the list the data you want, instead of updating. then you avoid having to deal with nullable values

Comment: @a_local_nobody where should I declare that car foo?

Comment: foo represents `tagOptions`

Comment: @a_local_nobody it returns `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0` this time (based on your suggestion `val tagOptions = emptyArray<String>()`

Comment: are you still using the same for loop ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes.

Comment: why would that work ? if an array is empty, trying to access index[i] will give you the exception as it currently does

Comment: this code : "var tagOptions = emptyArray<String>()
for (i in tags) {
  tagOptions = listOf(i.title).toTypedArray()
}" will set only last item to tagOptions

Comment: @АлександрВолошиновский how to fix it?

Comment: try this val tagOptions = ArrayList<String>()
for (i in tags) {
  tagOptions.add(i.title)
}

Comment: @АлександрВолошиновский then I get `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.` in `.setMultiChoiceItems(`

Comment: The problem is in var checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(false), here is only created an array with only one item, but for dialog you send an array with multimple data choose, checkedItems.size must be equal with tagOptions.size

Answer (score 1):

i did not work with volley but think the problem in threads, all network call are executed in background thread, seems like wen you press button "pTags" request is not finished, better make your button "pTags" inactive from start, write an callback when request is finish call your callback function and activate "pTags" button, and after this click on this.

**UPDATED**
The problem is in var checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(false), here is only created an array with only one item, but for dialog you send an array with multimple data choose, checkedItems.size must be equal with tagOptions.size
try this code:

```
val tagOptions = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in tags) {
        tagOptions.add(i.title)
    }
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
        .setTitle("dfsdfg")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(tagOptions.toTypedArray(), null) { dialog, which, checked ->
            // Respond to item chosen
            Log.d("eeee5", checkedItems.toString())
        }
        .show()
```

**Updated 1.1**

```
 var tagIds = ArrayList<Int>()
    var selectedIds = ArrayList<Int>()
    val tagOptions = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in tags) {
        tagOptions.add(i.title)
        tagIds.add(i.id) //i think 
    }

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
        .setTitle("dfsdfg")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(tagOptions.toTypedArray(), null) { dialog, which, checked ->
            // Respond to item chosen
            Log.d("eeee5", checkedItems.toString())
            if(checked){ //which IS INDEX
                selectedIds.add(which)
            }else {
                selectedIds.remove(which)
            }
        }
        .show()
```

access tagIds by selectedIds

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that it didn't make any difference, also if you see my code I've commented `Log.d("totalTags", tags.size.toString()) // returns: 387` so my `tags` value is not empty issue is somewhere else.

Comment: try this val tagOptions = ArrayList<String>()
for (i in tags) {
  tagOptions.add(i.title)
}

Comment: by using `tagOptions.toTypedArray()` it's showing all items, problem solved Thank you so much, but do you have any idea about my `PS` part (above update)?

Comment: Yse, the problem is in var checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(false), here is only created an array with only one item, but for dialog you send an array with multimple data choose, checkedItems.size must be equal with tagOptions.size

Comment: you neeed to create an boolean array with same size as tagOptions

Comment: no i meant this part `Ps: I also need my options to be included tag id's (is that possible to get both title and id into dialog options?`

Comment: What I need is this: **1** show `tags.title` as options (we already done that),  **2** send selected tags id `tags.id` to server. I need this second part now.

Comment: so each tag that is selected i need to collect id of that in order to send it to server later.

Comment: you can create one more array for ids, and use variable "which" to get index of choosen tags and with this index you can get id of selected tag

Comment: would you mind help me with this process as well?

Comment: check my answer, Updated 1.1

Comment: this return index of selected items right? then how do I get id of my `tags`? **note** my tags id are `uuid` not increaments so index of items in this list is not the same as my tags id

Comment: selectedIds.forEach{ index -> tagIds[index] }